# Custom Json Convert

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconvert

I need this json format to send in a request body:

```
{
"add": {
    "welcome_email": [
        "new_user_consented"
    ],
    "goodby_email": [
        "new_user_unconsented"
    ]
},
"audience
": {
     "user_id": [
                    "4520303589"
                ]
            }  
        }
```

I created a C# class

```
 public class TagsRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("Tags")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>> Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("audience")]
    public Audience Audience { get; set; }
}
```

When create an object from it and serialize is I get this result:

```
{
  "tags": {
    "add": [
      {
        "welcome_email": [
          "new_user_consented"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "audience": {
    "named_user": "joe"
  }
}
```

What should I do to get the proper result (the first one) from this class convertion?

Thanks advanced,

Comment: Why not `Dictionary<string, List<string>> Add`?

Comment: At the very least, you should format your question properly. Secondly, give us a [mre]. This is incomplete, for example, what is `Audience`?

Comment: Why do you declare `[JsonProperty("Tags")]` despite "Tags" not appearing as a property in your desired json output? What is going on here? (o.O)??? "_What should I do to get the proper result?_" Well, make your model classes match the data structure and property names from the desired Json structure you have shown in your question. Do not just use classes with arbitrary structure that doesn't match your Json structure and then wonder why you don't get the desired Json structure when serializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use a dictionary your  classes could be

```
Data data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("add")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Add { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("audience")]
    public Audience Audience { get; set; }
}

public partial class Audience
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public List<string> UserId { get; set; }
}
```

or if you can use a class instead of dictionary

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("add")]
    public Add Add { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("audience")]
    public Audience Audience { get; set; }
}
public partial class Add
{
    [JsonProperty("welcome_email")]
    public List<string> WelcomeEmail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("goodby_email")]
    public List<string> GoodbyEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Add
{
    [JsonProperty("welcome_email")]
    public List<string> WelcomeEmail{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("goodby_email ")]
    public List<string> GoodbyEmail{ get; set; }
}

public class Audience
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id ")]
    public List<string> UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Add Add { get; set; }
    public Audience Audience { get; set; }
}
```

Your models should be similar to this